# Character Rig: High deformation with bones

Tags: rigging

I need help for my character rig please, when i rotate on move on certain pose the bones the character got ultra high deformation like this screenshot:

[image]

[image]

God bless the one who fix my problem~

Comment: Can you share a blend file? This file doesn't contain any armature. You can use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload the file.

Comment: Im sorry for that i updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have irregular scale of armature:

[image]

Fix by doing this:

1. Select armature
2. Select object mode (instead of pose mode)
3. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

See also: [Why is it important to apply transformation to an objects data?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data/)